# Is there apt-get for windows?

Tags: debian, aptitude

If it was windows machine that had no internet connection, what I would do is downloading the installers/programs on another computer, putting them on a portable media, copying them on the conectionless machine and install them. Linux does not work that simple unfortunately - though I hope you'll prove me wrong on this point.

On linux (debian), I never had the pleasure installing anything differently than through:

```
sudo apt-get install package_name(s)
```

Thing impossible without connection to the internet. Unfortunately, it's also very unclear which files are to be downloaded - and from where. Often apt downloads dozens of files which is something I'd hate to do manually.

So, is there a program that would download the files on my Windows PC with no need to do anything more than telling it package name?

Comment: Chocolatey is used for silent-installation of programs on windows. Not for downloading debian packages.

Comment: "So, is there a program that would download the files on my Windows PC with no need to do anything more than telling it package name?"  Sounds like chocolatey to me.  @josten gave you a valid response, if you don't like it reword your question to ask what you really mean

Comment: *the files* is the important part. Could you define what did **you** understand that is meant by **the files**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for [apt-offline](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-offline).

On your Linux machine with no Internet connection, let's say you want to install emacs. You'd do:

```
# apt-offline set --install-packages=emacs /media/usbstick/offline.sig
```

Then, on your Windows machine with an Internet connection, you'd do:

```
E:\> apt-offline get offline.sig
```

and finally, on your Linux machine:

```
# apt-offline install /media/usbstick/offline.zip
```

Further details can be found in the article [Offline Package Management for APT](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT). Super User has some [help on adding apt-offline to your path on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/643528/apt-offline-on-windows).

Comment: `-bash: apt-offline: command not found`. Seems I'm out of luck.

Comment: @TomášZato You'll have to install it, and deal with dependencies once by hand. You can download the packages from that packages.debian.org site. You then install them on your Linux machine with `dpkg -i filename.deb`. (Or maybe its on the CD/DVD you used to install from, in which case you can install it from those)

Comment: Note: from the original Linux machine you can obtain the full list of packages with `dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list`. Just in case you want to use it...

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I have even succeeded mounting a pen drive to linux and generating `.sig` the files on it (not as simple as it may seem for beginner). However I can't seem to find any mention of the apt-offline windows download. The guide you linked to only contains link to some obscure site.

Comment: So, I have found a git hub repository. But the pain is endless - now I have found that [I can't build the thing](http://superuser.com/q/771044/194976).

Comment: @TomášZato make sure you're trying with python 2.x on Windows, not 3.x, at least so says one of those comments. I confess I've never actually run it on Windows...