# Offline Install of g++ for Debian

Tags: debian, gcc, gnu, debian-installer, g++

I have an offline Debian machine onto which I need to install g++, gdb, etc. (I believe it's the "build essentials" package.) I do *not* have access to an online Debian machine from which to get packages and sneakernet them over to the offline Debian machine. The only machines I have access to that have Internet access are Windows boxes.

How may I:

1. Obtain an offline installer using a Windows box (which I can sneakernet over to the offline Debian machine)
2. Use that offline installer to install g++, gdb, etc. onto the offline Debian box?

The offline Debian box has this version information:

> Linux 4.4.35-1-pve #1 SMP Fri Dec 9 11:09:55 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341951/download-debian-packages-and-dependancies-on-windows), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11519/updates-applications-packages-for-ubuntu-10-10-with-no-internet-connection/11521#11521), or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/336727/can-i-install-ubuntu-apt-get-packages-offline/336736#336736)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Debian machine already has the installer on it (`dpkg`), you just need the packages. You can manually grab them (using just a web browser) from https://packages.debian.org/. Note that you'll have to use the dependencies listed on that site to manually grab all the related packages. I'm not sure which Debian version you're running (Linux 4.4 isn't in a released Debian version), but running `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/debian_version` will tell you.

The site also gives expected checksums, so you can verify your manual downloads (otherwise, they won't be verified).

You can then copy these over however, and use `sudo dpkg -i package1.deb package2.deb ...` to install them all.

Alternatively, if you can spare the bandwidth, grab a [Debian DVD or Blu-ray image](https://www.debian.org/CD/). Those should both include all of build-essential (plus a lot more, especially the Blu-ray). You can add the disc to your `sources.list`, and then use apt/aptitude/etc. like normal.

If you have to do this at all frequently, look in to [apt-offline](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT). Which can run even on Windows. See [Is there apt-get for windows?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138119/is-there-apt-get-for-windows)

Comment: +1 to apt-offline and obtaining a cd/dvd/bluray/full mirror if possible.  If you at least have an initial set of index files for apt to use on a mirror, you can do `apt-get -dy install build-essential --print-uris  | grep -o '\'http.*\' | tr "\'" " "`   and it will print out a handy list of URLs you can grab using whatever method, then sneaker net them over and install them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Sushi Huh?

It is cross-platform so you should be able to download Linux programs and dependencies on a Windows machine and then transfer them to a Linux Machine.

> Sushi, huh? is a program that allows downloading all the packages needed to install the programs you want on GNU/Linux without an Internet connection on your own computer.
>   Sushi, huh? is designed for people, which for example can not afford monthly Internet connection.
>   As installing software on GNU/Linux is a hard and complex process for those newcomers to the world of GNU/Linux, which itself does not have an Internet connection, Sushi, huh? simplifies this task, making it as automatically as possible.

http://sushi-huh.sourceforge.net/